# Properties inside protocols in Swift

Tags: swift

Im learning swift. I need to ask what is the real use of properties when it is declared in protocol ?

```
import UIKit

protocol parentProtocol
{
    var firstName:String {get}
    func fullName() -> String
}

class childClass:parentProtocol
{
    var firstName = ""
    func fullName() -> String {
        firstName = "rajesh darak"
        return firstName
    }
}

var c = childClass()
c.fullName()
```

Though I'm declaring `firstName` as get (i.e read only), in the function itself I'm able to change the value of `firstName`.

Answer (score 1):

The protocol `parentProtocol` declares a requirement: anything that conforms to it must have a property `firstName` that is gettable. It's *not* saying that anything that inherits must be *only* gettable.

Why would you want this behaviour? Well, it's kind of a design choice, but here's an example of where it's useful: `CollectionType`. `CollectionType` has a property `count`. Now, for some of the operations you want to perform on `CollectionType`s, you *need* to have access to `count`. However, there's no need to confine things that inherit from it. For instance, `Array`'s count is read-only:

```
var ar = [1, 2, 3]

ar.count = 5 // What's supposed to happen here?!
```

But that doesn't mean that *every* `CollectionType` has to have a read-only count. `Repeat`, for instance has a variable `count`:

```
var re = Repeat(count: 3, repeatedValue: 0)   // [0, 0, 0]

re.count = 5                                  // [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

And it makes total sense for you to be able to change it.

Comment: Then what is use of writing get set properties if it is not going to follow it ? My question is what is the use of get , set when it is declared for a property which is inside protocols ?